# ImportError: cannot import name 'ExceptionReporterFilter'

Tags: python, django

Getting an error in my Django project.

`ImportError: cannot import name 'ExceptionReporterFilter'`

I'm using it in the following class

```py
from django.views.debug import ExceptionReporterFilter


class JSONExceptionReporterFilter(ExceptionReporterFilter):
    pass
```

I'm using `Django==2.2.1`

What can be the fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are actually using a newer version of Django where they renamed it to `SafeExceptionReporterFilter` or else your import would work as you are correct it is in 2.2.1 as you can see in the code https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.1/django/views/debug.py#L109

You can look to see what version of django you are running with the following in your code (near your error)

```
import django
print(django.__version__)
```

Comment: Thanks!
I forgot to check the version of Django.